# Why won't this image show?

Tags: html, image

I am currently working on a portfolio for my website. I added my picture in it, but the picture does not show.

```
<div id="wrap">
    <h1>Portfolio/CV</h1>
    <ul id="gallery">
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <img src="logo.png"> <!-- doesn't show -->
            <div>These are coming soon!</div>
          </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

You can see above html live on my [portfolio](http://www.anika.nl/portfolio.html).

I have uploaded the image to my server.

Does somebody understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: your link does not work.

Comment: I guess you need to paste some html code or something that you are trying your hands on. Or give the llink

Comment: http://www.anika.nl/portfolio.html - your image paths are wrong. Are images in same directory as your portfolio.html file? (since first path i checked is 'logo.png', i guess that's not the case)...

Comment: Yes they are in the same directory...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Paste your relevant HTML & CSS code, which shows the problem, or create a [demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net) here.

Comment: http://www.anika.nl/logo.png - how did you created that images?

Comment: It could be issues in **name, format(check png/jpeg) or path**. Nothing else would be the issue if **uploaded successfully**.

Answer (score 0):

this is how your HTML looks, when you are able to access those links your site will work. Seems your images are uploaded to a different folder or maybe permission to read is not there.
http://www.anika.nl/logo.png

```
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
        <h1>Portfolio/CV</h1>
        <ul id="gallery">
            <li><a href="#"><img src="logo.png"><div>These are coming soon!</div></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="lights2.jpg"><div>I am working on it!</div></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="flo3.jpg"><div>Why are you even reading this?</div></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="lights1.jpg"><div>Humans are always so curious</div></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="flo2.jpg"><div>LOL </div></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="lights3.jpg"><div>Can't stop?</div></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```